# Node placement problem

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

This is my first question in tex.stackexchange. It might be relatively simple problem but I am having difficulties with the placement of the nodes inside graphics.

The problem is that when I try to compile the code below I get the result which has problem.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[thick,ticks=none,domain=-pi:pi,samples=1000,axis x line=middle,axis y line=none,xlabel={t},xmin=-4,xmax=7,ymax=2,ymin=-2]
\addplot[smooth, color=black] (\x,{sin((9*(deg(x))) )*cos(((deg(x))) )}) node[pos=0.75,pin={carrier wave},thick,inner sep=0pt] {};
\addplot[smooth, color=black] (\x,{cos(((deg(x))) )}) ;
\addplot[smooth, color=black] (\x,{-cos(((deg(x))) )}) node[pos=0.75,pin={envelope wave},thick,inner sep=0pt] {};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

It should look like this (look at the position of the pinned text):

[image]

Once it was working but now it is not working.

Comment: sorry, what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Your code compiles without mishap on my machine. What is your question, exactly? "Once it was working but now it is not working" does not give us much information.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). It is better to turn your code snippet into a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) starting with `\documentclass` ending with `\end{document}` and including only the necessary packages that reproduce the problem. This will help who wants to answer you. `:)`

Comment: you can look at this link http://i45.tinypic.com/wgyus5.png
 to see the problem
I think, I have a compiler options problem.

Comment: So the problem is that the arrow and `carrier wave` is not in the correct location? It's important to provide an MWE as @ClaudioFiandrino stated, otherwise we can't determine which options might be interfering with your image.

Comment: @Mythio, Here is the problem, http://i46.tinypic.com/b6q5hi.png ,I cannot change the position it always gets the lower left as reference. Changing angle changes the angle but position is fixed.
`code` \addplot[smooth, color=black] (\x,{sin((9*(deg(x))) )*cos(((deg(x))) )}) node[pos=0.93,pin=85:{carrier wave},thick] {};
\addplot[smooth, color=black] (\x,{cos(((deg(x))) )}) ;
\addplot[smooth, color=black] (\x,{-cos(((deg(x))) )}) node[pos=0.52,pin=10:{envelope wave},thick] {};

Comment: I think the problem is that the text is not appearing correctly in relation to the image, i.e. not as in the example. I've provided an MWE in your question. Unfortunately, I have no idea whats causing this.

Comment: @Mythio I do not understand what causes the problem but if I change the nodes to be on the right of the curve it has no problem \documentclass{standalone} \usepackage{pgfplots}\begin{document} \begin{figure}[ht]\centering\begin{tikzpicture} \begin{axis}[thick,ticks=none,domain=-pi:pi,samples=1000,axis x line=middle,axis y line=none,xlabel={t},xmin=-4,xmax=9,ymax=2,ymin=-2]
\addplot[smooth](\x,{sin((9*(deg(x))))*cos(((deg(x))) )}) node[right]{carier wave};
\addplot[smooth](\x,{cos(((deg(x))))}) ;
\end{axis}\end{tikzpicture} \end{figure}\end{document}

Answer (score 2):

Try this (I just fixed the positions and angles for the pins):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[thick,ticks=none,domain=-pi:pi,samples=1000,axis x line=middle,axis y line=none,xlabel={t},xmin=-4,xmax=7,ymax=2,ymin=-2]
\addplot[smooth, color=black] (\x,{sin((9*(deg(x))) )*cos(((deg(x))) )}) node[pos=0.93,pin={[pin distance=1cm]75:carrier wave},thick,inner sep=0pt] {};
\addplot[smooth, color=black] (\x,{cos(((deg(x))) )}) ;
\addplot[smooth, color=black] (\x,{-cos(((deg(x))) )}) node[pos=0.5,pin={290:envelope wave},thick,inner sep=0pt] {};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Another option would be to use `coordinate`s instead of `node`s and use something like `shorten <=\pgflinewidth` for the `pin edge` if one wants to preserve the little space that the node occupies.