# Placing node at path using `midway` in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, coordinates

I thought my problem would have been possibly answered anywhere here, but I could not get it to work. Questions I consider linked to mine but which weren´t able to solve my issue are [node placement problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/106676/41356) and [pgfplots: placing node on a specific x-position](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88404/41356).

I want to make an annotation to a graph drawn using `pgfplots` (actually, its inside a `groupplots`-environment). I tried so using the PGF-command `draw[<-> (pos a) node [midway,...] -- (pos b)`. However, the node did not get placed midways, but in the middle of nowhere. This is not true for `below` and `above`. However, the same thing happens when I used `near end` or `pos=???`.

I worked around this issue just placing a node manually at the place where I want it. However, I don´t find this very satisfactory. Feel free to have a look at the MWE below.

---

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[{hide y axis,
axis x line=middle,
height=3cm, width=10cm,
xmin=-22.5, xmax=83,
samples=200,
xtick={-20, 0,20, 40, 60, 80}}]

\addplot+[domain=-20:80,mark=none,green]{sin(40*.18*x)};

% % % % % The erroneous part:
% 1.:
\draw[<->,green!70!black,thick] (axis cs:40,0) 
node[midway, above,font=\scriptsize] {$\varphi_1$} % This SHOULD work, but doesn´t
 -- (axis cs:50,0);

% 2.: 
\node[font=\scriptsize,green!70!black] at (axis cs:45,.3) {$\varphi_1$}; %This does work

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I also know it would be nice to calculate the intersection. I tried to understand the answers [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21409/41356) and [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/96565/41356), but I couldn´t. Maybe its overkill for a little bit of sine...

Comment: You need `\draw[<->,green!70!black,thick] (axis cs:40,0) 
 -- (axis cs:50,0) node[midway, above,font=\scriptsize] {$\varphi_1$};`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to place the node either at the end of the path:

```
\draw[<->,green!70!black,thick] 
  (axis cs:40,0) -- (axis cs:50,0) node[midway, above,font=\scriptsize] {$\varphi_1$};
```

or after the `to` part:

```
\draw[<->,green!70!black,thick] 
  (axis cs:40,0) -- node[midway, above,font=\scriptsize] {$\varphi_1$} (axis cs:50,0);
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  hide y axis,
  axis x line=middle,
  height=3cm, width=10cm,
  xmin=-22.5, xmax=83,
  samples=200,
  xtick={-20, 0,20, 40, 60, 80}
]
\addplot+[domain=-20:80,mark=none,green]{sin(40*.18*x)};

\draw[<->,green!70!black,thick] 
  (axis cs:40,0) -- node[midway, above,font=\scriptsize] {$\varphi_1$} (axis cs:50,0);
\draw[<->,red!70!black,thick] 
  (axis cs:10,0) -- (axis cs:20,0) node[midway, above,font=\scriptsize] {$\varphi_2$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks again for the fast answer! I always though I could define the node in the middle... proved to be wrong.

Comment: @Paul You're welcome! Indeed, you can place the node in the middle, but *after* the `to` part (see second example in my updated answer).

Comment: Ah, so I got that mixed up. Thanks for clarification!